# QT Arbitrary View Widget

Tags: qt

[plz click here to show the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCeMC.png)

I want to create a set of UI like this.
I don't have source code, but I knew it's done by QT.
So I guess, overall, this is QTreeView
but how is its ChildWidget done?

All the child are different,
There are QCheckBox,
There are QLabel + QLineEdit
There are QTreeView too.

So I want to know how the child widgets are created and inserted to the QTreeView?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html

ChildWidget are created by *delegate*. You can read more about delegate in [Qt Model/View architecture](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html)